# How do I set the fixed background image in my Ionic 4 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using `Ionic 4`. On my Login Page whenever keyboard is pressed, background image scrolls up. I found no workaround until now.

I applied below `css` to `ion-content`:

```
ion-content{
 --background: #fff url('/assets/img/bigscren.jpg') no-repeat center center / cover !important;
 --background-size: cover !important;
 --background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

This is my front page:

```
<ion-content padding>
//My Content
</ion-content>
```

I also applied `fixed` attribute to `ion-content` (from latest [ionic doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#css-custom-properties)) but that also not working.

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: can you try overflow:none

Comment: Sure. Please let me check

Comment: @VarunSukheja `overflow:none` is not working

Comment: How does it scroll up? Because of your keyboard who shows up or every time you press a key it goes up? Can you clarify?

Comment: @TomasVancoillie Everytime when I click on Input keyboard appears and image goes to top(scrolls up) and when keyboard is cancelled or dismissed it scrolls down(and fits to screen).